# How is it possible to create QT C++ GUI cards dynamically

Tags: c++, qt

With SQLite i am able to retrieve data and able to assign the value for existing lables in the GUI Window. But I need to create Cards where Topics texts buttons are included in each card. I am unable to figure out the approach.

In C# like languages we can just use a while loop and Initiate The component name and assign the properties.

I am creating a desktop GUI application

Comment: Do you know how to create objects in C++ dynamically using `new`? Then you know how to create Qt components dynamically as well. Create the GUI class any way you please (for example in Qt Designer), and use `new` to create an instance of it.

Comment: What component can i use as a card to fix all the labels and buttons in it ?

Comment: Can you clarify what's your issue exactly? You're having issues creating 'cards' for each row you retrieve from the database, using something like QTabWidget? Or you want to add additional fields to some 'cards' depending what data you read, like additional labels/buttons/text fields?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.